# How to add a new column in relation to existing column in MySql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have already an existing Table, named "table1" in my MySql database, for example, it has one column named, "subject", which contains value like this:

[image]

now i want to add an new column in "table1", named "code", which will contains values:

for "AAAA" in "subject" is "S01",

for "BBBB" in "subject" is "S02",

for "CCCC" in "subject" is "S03",

for "DDDD" in "subject" is "S04".

as shown here:

[image]

how the SQL Query would be for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a case  eg for select

```
select  subject 
    , case  
        when subject  ='AAAA' then 'S01'
        when subject  ='BBBB' then 'S02'
        when subject  ='CCCC' then 'S03'
        when subject  ='DDDD' then 'S04'  
    end  code 
from my_table
```

and if you need  update the content of the table

```
update my_table  
set code = case  
        when subject  ='AAAA' then 'S01'
        when subject  ='BBBB' then 'S02'
        when subject  ='CCCC' then 'S03'
        when subject  ='DDDD' then 'S04'  
    end
```

you can add  the column to the table schema using

```
ALTER TABLE my_table    ADD  code  varchar(4) ;
```

And for string that start with 'AAAA' you can use  `like` operator

```
 when subject  like 'AAAA%' then 'S01'
```